# django not filtering datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am working on a news website using django and I would like to allow users to search **articles** by **date**

This is the Article model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,null=False,blank=False)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    resume=models.CharField(null=False,blank=False,max_length=400)
```

Right now I have two articles with the following dates (**datetime**)

**2018-05-21 11:12:03.868542**

**2018-05-22 19:02:12.885298**

When I run this on the django shell

```
articles=Article.objects.filter(date__day=21,date__month=05,date__year=2018)
```

I get an empty queryset

Comment: Why not just do `Article.objects.filter(date__date=date(2018, 05, 21))`?

Comment: Are you using Python-3.x? In Python-3.x `05` is an invalid integer literal.

Comment: Are these articles stored in the database? Since constructing two `Article` instances is *not* enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using the contains filter.

```
articles=Article.objects.filter(date__contains=datetime.date(2018,5,21))
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be connected with time zone. May be 2018-05-21 11:12:03 in your zone is actually 2018-05-20 01:12:03 in GMT. To check how Python interprets your time zone, read your Article objects from the database without filter and write **day** and **month** to the console. Then you will know what to use in your filter.

Comment: The date I wrote was taken from the database and this is what I get when I print the date of the first article in django shell : datetime.datetime(2018,5,21,11,12,3,868542,tzinfo=(UTC))

Comment: It works if I filter with only the year but If I try to include the day and the month it doesn't work

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi: The output looks good. Anyway check following. What happens when you filter by year and month without date? If it works, try adding the day 20, then 22. Will it be found with one of these days? If yes, it means there is stimm some problem with date conversion and timezone.

Comment: Thanks but I have solved the problem. I used this and it worked : articles=Article.objects.filter(date__contains=datetime.date(2018,5,21))

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi: Post your solution as an answer to your question and mark it as the accepted answer. This will help others who have similar question. Yes, it is fine if you answer your own question. Do not hesitate :)

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
articles=Article.objects.filter(date__day=21,date__month=5,date__year=2018)
```

Use 5 instead of 05,in Python 3 any integer preceding 0 is invalid integral.